# Evince presentation mode keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, evince

I can't find a list of keyboard shortcuts for Evince. I checked Gnome wiki and askubuntu.

Does anybody happen to know the shortcut for presentation mode or can point me to a list of shortcuts?

Comment: It's all in the [official documentation](https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/index.html.en)

Comment: @don_crissti i could only find theese few https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/shortcuts.html.en

Comment: This is because you did _not_ read the documentation - if you follow the link in my post and go to [Presentations](https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/presentations.html.en) it does say pretty clear that _"To start a presentation: [...](or **click F5**)"_ doesn't it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**F5** for presentation. F11 for fullscreen. The [shortcuts](https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/shortcuts.html.en) are next to the items in the GUI menu for my Evince version (3.18.2).

Comment: Update Feb 2019: can't confirm this for neither in Debian's stable (3.22.1-3+deb9u1) nor testing (3.30.2-3)..

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to start `evince` in presentation mode automatically from the command line:

```
$ evince -s file.pdf
```

`man evince` says:

> -s, --presentation
>
> ```
>    Run evince in presentation mode.
> ```